# How do you interpret this #define va_ arg(list,mode) ( (mode *) ( list += sizeof(mode) ) [-1]

Tags: c, unix

```
#define va_arg(list,mode) ( (mode *) ( list += sizeof(mode) ) [-1]
```

I don't know `[-1]` how to see?  Can the pointer point to this position?

i think this points to the previous value in mode

Comment: It advances the array to the next element and then dereferences the previous element.

Comment: That does not look like actual code. First, there is one more `(` than `)`. Second, defining `va_` to expand to something beginning with `_arg(list,mode)` is weird. Was the original code perhaps `#define va_arg(list,mode) ( (mode *) ( list + = sizeof(mode) ) [-1] )`?

Comment: Also `+ =` should be `+=`. When reproducing text to ask questions, you should copy and paste it exactly or ensure you ahve exactly reproduced the text, character for character, with no changes at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `#define va_arg(list,mode) ( (mode *) ( list += sizeof(mode) ) [-1]`

That is an implementation of the `va_arg` macro to be defined by `<stdarg.h>` for C’s variable arguments features in C 2018 7.16.

When this macro is used, `list` should be a `va_list` object, and `mode` should be a type. In this C implementation, `va_list` is apparently implemented as a pointer to a character type or as a pointer to `void` in a C implementation that extends pointer arithmetic to work with `void *`.

Then `list += sizeof(mode)` advances `list` by the number of bytes in an object of type `mode`, to account for the argument that is about to be “consumed” by the macro. Then the `(mode *)` cast preceding `( list += sizeof(mode) )` converts the pointer to point to the desired type. However, due to the `+=`, it is now pointing after the desired argument, and that pointer value is the result of the `+=` expression and the cast. So the `[-1]` after it is used to fetch the element just prior to where `list` is pointing.

I suspect this slightly awkward construction with `[-1]` was used to avoid using `list` twice in the macro, which is good practice to avoid evaluating side effects more than once, in case the macro argument is an expression with side effects.

Note that using `list` in `list += sizeof(mode)` is probably an error or oversight; it should be `(list) += sizeof(mode)`.

Comment: "Then the (mode *) cast preceding ( list += sizeof(mode) ) converts the pointer to point to the desired type" No, since `[-1]` takes precedence over the cast operator, the `[-1]` pointer arithmetic is applied first, before casting.

Comment: It is also questionable how the `(mode*)` cast followed by de-referencing on the caller side results in well-defined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin: Re “precedence”: That explains where OP’s missing `)` went. They edited to correct it, so I edited to match. Re “results in well-defined behavior”: Code **in** the C implementation is the responsibility of the C implementation; it is free to use constructs not defined by the C standard and to define them itself.

Comment: `va_arg` is a macro that will get expanded in the caller code, not inside the standard lib.

Comment: @Lundin: The C implementation is free to define it. It is **in** the C implementation in the sense it is code provided by the implementation. As long as the C implementation defines the behavior such that the code it provides works as specified, that is fine. There is no obligation for the C standard to provide code in its headers that will work in other C implementations.

Comment: Since the code as-is will likely cause misaligned access, it will not even work on the intended implementation. And I doubt this is actually what the lib looks like.

Comment: @Lundin: You have not been told what the intended implementation is or whether it supports unaligned loads. Your doubts about what the library looks like are irrelevant; if you have an issue with that, take it up with the OP.